"The operation is not supported by the object" when trying to delete any partition/volume
I'm trying to delete the recovery partition because it's in between two spaces I'm trying to merge - when I try to execute delete vol override or delete part override, this error shows:
The operation is not supported by the object

The specified command or parameters are not supported on this system



Has WinRE been disabled via ReAgentC /Disable?

@JW0914 Yes I disabled it

Is the Recovery partition the issue is with an OEM WinRE partition? Please post a snippet of Disk Management [DiskMgmt.msc] to show the partition and free space layout

@JW0914 here

(Please edit your question to add additional info =]) I don't know why this issue exists, but I do know you have an incorrect partition layout in general. To resolve the deletion issue, try booting to WinPE (a Windows install USB - Press Shift+F10 to access a terminal once the GUI loads), as you can't boot to WinRE to delete it since it's the WinRE partition, even if it wasn't disabled. OS drive should always have the following partition layout: EFI, MSR, OS, WinRE. WinRE should always be on the OS drive, else there's no recovery partition to boot to if the other drive is removed.

(Cont'd...) To add WinRE to the OS drive, use diskpart's shrink command on the OS partition, following step #3 once booted back to Windows, then ReAgentC /Enable and remove the WinRE partition's mountpoint via DiskPart

Disk Management treats the recovery partition as protected, so you need
to use diskpart to forcefully remove it.
For a Basic format disk :

Run an elevated Command Prompt
Enter the command ReAgentC /Disable
Enter the command diskpart
Use the following sub-commands:

list disk - to present all disks on your computer
select disk x – where x is the number of the disk
list partition – to display all partitions on the disk
select partition y – where y is the number of the partition
delete partition override



For a dynamic format disk :

Use the following diskpart commands:

list volume – to list all volumes
select volume x – where x is the number of the volume to remove
delete volume override



For more information see
Fixed: Diskpart Delete Partition Override Not Working.

The same error in the question occures when I do delete volume override

Which partition are you trying to delete?

The recovery one, and I disabled the WinRE agent by the way

I don't see a recovery partition in the image.
